# Traer datos de hasta 5 días de antiguedad

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Necesito hacer una consulta que traiga los datos de hasta 5 días de antigüedad teniendo en cuenta la fecha actual de la consulta y la fecha de creación del evento.

En mi modelo Event.php tengo el metodo newEventAdmin() con el siguiente código

```
public function newEventAdmin()
{
    $newEvent = Event::whereBetween('created_at', array(Carbon::now(), Carbon::now()->subDay(5)))
                       ->where('status', '=', 'PENDING')
                       ->get();
    return view('backend.events.neweventadmin', compact('newEvent'));                    
}
```

Alguna idea? Ocupo laravel 5,6

Comment: cual es el resultado que te arroja

Comment: Me arroja $newEvent vació

Comment: Solucionado el problema, te pasaste con tu ayuda!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás cometiendo dos errores pequeños al momento de hacer la consulta:

1. Primero debería ir la fecha que está más atrás en el tiempo (hace 5 días) y luego la posterior (hoy).
2. Estás usando subDay() que es para restar solo un día, cuando deberías usar subDays(5), en plural.

La consulta quedaría así:

```
Event::whereBetween('created_at', [Carbon::now()->subDays(5), Carbon::now()])
                   ->where('status', '=', 'PENDING')
                   ->get();
```

Comment: Exacto, asì tal cual la hice y funciono, muchas gracias por tu gran ayuda!